# Does Redux dispatch fires full component reloading

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have app with forms, after typescript rewritting (strict), I notice that now any ThunkDispatch dispatch from store fires full component reloading (constructor, ComponentDidMount) opposite to SetState.

I have header warning component, that display alerts if store contains object with non null message. If I dispatch change of this messsage in another component, this component reloads, lost local state calls constructor, ComponentDidmount e.t.c.

Is it correct behavior or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: It may be because you're using that redux store in the parent of the component being reloaded, so if the parent component is re-rendering, so the child component will reload, props will pass again and constructor runs again.

Comment: Yes, it is. I Wrapped props in parent component to "subparent" and reloading is gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Whatever is causing your unintentional refreshes must be caused by a component higher up in your application that is being affected by the redux state changes.

When the wrapping component subscribed to the redux state experiences a state change, it will re-render. This could cause a change in which components are mounted/unmounted.